# Application of Fubini's theorem (in a proof of energy minimizing harmonic maps)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in H^1(B_1,S^k)$, where $B_1$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S^k$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Suppose that $u$ is a minimizer for the Dirichlet energy functional
$$
I[w]=\int_{B_1}|Dw|^2dx
$$ I have to prove that I can find some $r\in (0,1/2)$ such that
$$
\int_{\partial B_r}|u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x\le 3\int_{B_1} |u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
where
$$
\bar{u}=\frac{1}{|B_1|}\int_{B_1}u\,dx
$$

Comment: What makes you think this should be true? One could change $u$ in $B_1\setminus B_{1/2}$ to make the second integral $0$. In general, comparing integrals like this for sphere-valued functions looks odd.

Comment: Do you want to prove that estimate for *all* $r$ or *some* $r$? Please include a quantifier in your claim.

Comment: For some $r$! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the claim is not true.
Then for all $r\in(0,1/2)$ you have
$$
\int_{\partial B_r}|u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x > 3\int_{B_1} |u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Integrate this inequality with respect to $r$ from zero to $\frac12$; integrating the surface integrals with respect to radius gives a volume integral.
You get
$$
\int_{B_{1/2}}|u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x > \frac32\int_{B_1} |u-\bar{u}|^2\, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
But this is impossible since the integrand is positive, $B_{1/2}\subset B_1$ and $\frac32>1$.
Therefore the claim is indeed true.

This observation has little to do with $u$ being a minimizer.
You only need $u$ to be regular enough in order to make sense of (almost all) surface integrals and apply Fubini's theorem.